# Have Canvas Image Move Upwards in A Loop

Tags: javascript, loops, canvas

I'm making an image matching game and I currently have a set image on my screen (the one that needs to be matched with) and a fading image as well (the one that needs to move up to match with the set image). Right now I'm stuck on actually having the image that needs to move upwards to be matched to the set image. (**Basically think of Dance Dance Revolution**). Once the fading and moving upwards image has reached the set image up top, I want to be able to press the arrow keys to be able to match the moving image with the set image.

`So far I have a canvas and a timeout attached to the canvas to adjust the speed at which the moving image is fading.

Example of code so far:

index.html

```
<div>
  <img src="images/birdShadow.png" alt="shadow bird">
</div>

#canvas
<canvas id="bird" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
<script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById('birds');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var x = 50;
  var y = 30;
  var width = 100;
  var height = 100;
  var newBirds = new Image();

  //bird
  newBirds.onload = function(){
     context.drawImage(newBirds, x, y, width, height);
     context.clearBird(0, 0, canvas.width);
  };
  newBirds.src = 'images/yellowBird.png';
</script>

birdFlys.js

function loadHTML(){
   fetch('index.html')
}

function changeBirds(){
   var canvas = document.getElementById("birds");
   canvas.src = birds[x];
   x++;
   if(x>=birds.length){
       x=0;
   }
   fadeCanvas(canvas, 100, true);
     setTimeout("changeBirds()", 3000);
}

function fadeCanvas(i, e, fade) {
    if(fade === true ) {
        e--;
    } else {
        e++;
    }
    if(e > 0 && e <100) {
        i.style.opacity = e / 100;
        setTimeout(function() { fadeCanvas(i, e, fade); }, 10);
    }
}

//the rate at which the birds fade 
var birds = [], x = 0;
setTimeout("changeBirds()", 3000);
`
```

`